# rails scope "expires_within"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Hey guys. I have a model, `Item`, which is set to "expire" in `created_at + 100.days`. I am trying to create a scope that will return the items which will expire in a supplied time, such as `10.days`.

So far I have this:

```
scope :expires_within, lambda {|time| where("created_at > ?", time)}
```

So that I could eventually do something like:

```
Item.expires_within(10.days)
```

Which would return a collection of items which expire within 10 days.

This isn't right, I just wanted to have a skeleton of what I should have. I can't figure out if it's possible to do this through a scope or not. It seems to me like I would be able to if I had a column in the table called `expires_at`, but the problem is that I would rather not create such a column because I want the expiration time, above stated as `created_at + 100.days`, to be flexible.

I just wanted to see if it would be possible without such a column, or if it can be done but not with a scope, I'd like to hear that possibility as well. If not, I'll go ahead and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution I believe. I will continue to test it.

```
scope :expires_within, lambda {|time| where("created_at < ?", time.from_now - 100.days)}
```

Basically my original formula to calculate whether something was expired was:

```
Time.now > created_at + 100.days
```

Since I want to determine whether something expires within a future time (e.g. 10.days), I add it to the left-hand side:

```
Time.now + time > created_at + 100.days
```

Remember, 100.days is how long an item has to live before it expires.

Finally, I solve for `created_at` so that it's by itself, since that's what the sql query demands, by subtracting `100.days` from the other side:

```
created_at < (Time.now + time) - 100.days
```

This could be made more concise, as Ryan pointed out, by doing:

```
created_at < time.from_now - 100.days
```

Basic math I guess. I'm still pretty dazed from thinking about it too hard, so I will test it a bit to make sure it works as intended. If it does, `Item.expires_within(10.days)` should return a collection of items which will expire within 10 days (or before).

**EDIT**: I've refactored this to ignore the items which have already expired. So the new scope looks for the items that have not yet expired and will expire within a specified time frame:

```
scope :expires_within, lambda {|time| where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 100.days.ago, time.from_now - 100.days)}
```

Answer (score 2):

`from_now` would do this:

```
10.days.from_now
```

Or dynamically:

```
scope :expires_within, lambda {|time| where("created_at > ?", time.from_now)}
```

Comment: Something fishy going on here: `created_at > [10 days in the future]`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scope for...

```
scope :expires_within_10_days, lambda { where('created at > ?', 90.days.ago) }
```

...which should fetch all items that were created over 90 days ago, which means they expire within 10 days. Add another condition to exclude already-expired items.

*Update: Switched example to a scope, versus regular AR query...*

Comment: This looks promising. Can you reword it so that one can input 10.days? Oh, it would just be 100.days - 10.days. Thanks I will try this.